# Js Carousel not working when added to site

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Help I found code for a logo carousel which I want to add to my site, however when I write the code into my site the carousel doesn't work at all. all the files have been placed into the right location.

I think the problem is with where I placed the link for the JS file in the HTML file?

```
    <div class="container">
      <section class="customer-logos slider">
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img/Mascot_logo.jpg"></div>
      </section>
    </div>





      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>

      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's a link with more detailed code

Comment: Due to javascript conflicts may be possible that slider not working. check console log to check js issues.

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely isn't where you placed the link, it's that you didn't call any functions to initiate the carousel. I see you used `slick.js` -- you have to call something like `$('.slider').slick();` to start it up. Slick will have documentation for all of that.

Comment: I have '$('.customer-logos').slick' in a .js file, would it be better if I included this in the html document?

Comment: no, that probably wouldn't make a difference. Just make sure you're calling it correctly.

Comment: Sorry fairly new to this but here is some of my code if you could have a look and see where the problem is (https://jsfiddle.net/Webi13/qvsdgbk2/)

Comment: In the console it's saying '$().slick() is not a function' I'm not sure what's going wrong here, if you're loading the files in the wrong order or using an incompatible version of jquery. Try starting from scratch, just keeping your div with your images you want to be a slider, take all your external sources out and add them one by one until it's working.

Comment: okay I've stripped everything down and started again, adding everything back section by section. The slider was working until I added this last bit of code... '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'

Comment: This was all done in JSFiddle, however when I copied the "working code" into my actual HTML doc it stops working completely (jsfiddle.net/Webi13/qvsdgbk2)

Comment: First of all it looked like you had 2 version of jquery in your document, which is a problem, and second of all it looked like you put slick before jquery, which i think you're not supposed to do, but I can't guarantee that fixing those problems will make it work because I tried that myself and it wasn't working.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, ill play around with it and see what happens